# Call function after ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax function that triggers when I click it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
        $("#single-post-container").html('<img src="image.png">');
        $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
                        return false;
    });          
});
```

But AFTER I've triggered it, I would like to call a new function. A function for a slideshow in jQuery. I've google alot and I see that if you put new functions in the "success: " section in ajax it will work.. But mine does not have an success section? I understand if I make you laugh, I'm as amateur as it gets! Haha. But Please, if you need more info, let me know.

Thanks!

(The function I'm trying to add is this:)

```
$(function(){


var width = 600;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;


var $slider = $("#slider");
var $slideContainer = $(".slides");
var $slides = $(".slide");
var $toggleRight = $("#right");
var $toggleLeft = $("#left");


$toggleRight.click(function(){
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed,     function(){
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 1;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
    });
});

$toggleLeft.click(function(){
    if (currentSlide === 1) {
        currentSlide = $slides.length;
        $slideContainer.css({'margin-left': '-'+width*($slides.length-1)+'px'});
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            currentSlide--;
        });
    } else {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
            currentSlide--;
        });
    }
});




});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your new function in `callback function` of **[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**. For ex:

```
$("#single-post-container").load(post_link,function(){
    //Call new function here
});
```

**Callback Function**

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and `HTML` insertion has been performed. The callback
>   is fired once for each element in the `jQuery` collection, and this is
>   set to each `DOM` element in turn.

Alongside you can check whether load was `success` or `failed` using `status` parameter from the `callback function` as below:

```
$("#single-post-container").load(post_link,function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if (status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
  else
  {
     //Call new function
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Look at my question again, I added the function!

Comment: give that `function` a name and call it after `load` @Snik1

Comment: Thank you very much, but the thing is that when I do this now, the page redirects when I click .post-link... Any suggestions?

Comment: `$(".post-link").click(function(e){e.preventDefault() //other codes as it its })` @Snik1 Prevent the default action...

Comment: So in my JS I put all of the new function in 
** function myNewFunction(){
//HERE
}
 **
And call it after load?

Comment: Keep `$(".post-link").click(..)` outside function and yea remaining whatever mentioned in `$(function(){` name it as `function hello(){all the other code}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89783/discussion-between-snik1-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that load is asynchronous. The function call returns before the AJAX request is complete. If you have code that needs to be executed after the request is complete, you need to use the complete/success callback.

[More Info](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

you can do like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$(".post-link").click(function(){
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
    $("#single-post-container").html('<img src="image.png">');
    $("#single-post-container").load(post_link, function( response, status, xhr ) {
   if(status=="success"){

     var width = 600;
     var animationSpeed = 1000;
     var pause = 3000;
     var currentSlide = 1;


     var $slider = $("#slider");
     var $slideContainer = $(".slides");
     var $slides = $(".slide");
     var $toggleRight = $("#right");
     var $toggleLeft = $("#left");


    $toggleRight.click(function(){
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
    currentSlide++;
    if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
        currentSlide = 1;
        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
    }
});
});

   $toggleLeft.click(function(){
if (currentSlide === 1) {
    currentSlide = $slides.length;
    $slideContainer.css({'margin-left': '-'+width*($slides.length-1)+'px'});
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
        currentSlide--;
    });
} else {
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide--;
    });
        }
     });

     }
      if ( status == "error" ) {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
      }
                    return false;
   });          
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Look at my question again, I added the function!

Comment: see the edited answer. but this will be a quick solution for your problem. i suggest you to read more on JavaScript patterns/Practices. ex: you can make that as a separate function and call it inside success.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the thing is that when I do this now, the page redirects when I click .post-link... Any suggestions?

Comment: normal behavior of load is to Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. so according to your scenario it should replace the #single-post-container div with the contents.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/): "When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified")"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#main-content").fadeIn(500);
        $("#single-post-container").html('<img src="image.png">');
        $("#single-post-container").load(post_link, 
         function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
              // all good!
            }
            if (textStatus == "error") {
              // oh noes!
            });
                            return false;
         });          
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Look at my question again, I added the function!